# Full Frequency Array Reconstruction after numpy.fft.rfftn

Tags: python, numpy, dft, slice

I have a real valued grayscale 3D image with resolution rows x cols x deps. I take the dft of the image using `freq = numpy.fft.rfftn(myImage)`

The returned array, freq, is resolution: rows x cols x deps/2 + 1. I want to reconstruct freq as if it were the output of `numpy.fft.fftn(myImage)`, that is, I want the dimensions of freq to be rows x cols x deps.

I know that the correspondence for real-valued dft is X_(k1,k2,k3) = X*_(N1-k1,N2-k2,N3-k3) where * is the conjugate transpose.

I could reconstruct the full freq array using a loop, but that'll be too slow, but I'm having trouble figuring out the correct way of doing it with array slicing.

Thanks!

FYI, I need the full array because I'll be element wise multiplying it with another array of full size rows x cols x deps, I cannot assume that array has any structure (like symmetry) that would make it unnecessary for me to reconstruct the full freq array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!

```
import numpy as np
import time

rows = 181
cols = 217
deps = 181

jac_k = np.random.rand(rows, cols, deps)*5

prev = time.time()
fft1 = np.fft.fftn(jac_k)
print time.time() - prev

prev = time.time()
fft2 = np.fft.rfftn(jac_k)

if deps%2 == 0:
    fft2Star = np.conj(fft2[:, :, -2:0:-1])
else:
    fft2Star = np.conj(fft2[:, :, -1:0:-1])

fft2Star[1::, :, :] = fft2Star[:0:-1, :, :]
fft2Star[:, 1::, :] = fft2Star[:, :0:-1, :]

fft2 = np.concatenate( (fft2, fft2Star), axis=2)
print time.time() - prev

print np.linalg.norm(fft1 - fft2)
```